# Getting image source through jQuery isn't working in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

This is my website www.aqurds and I am using jQuery in my portfolio section to make the image large by getting the image source when the click event is triggered. The code is working in firefox and IE but not working in chrome. Here is the code

```
var floatinMother = $('.floatingimagecontainermother'),
floating = $('.floatingimagecontainer');

$('.zoomsign').on("click", function(){
    var zoomsign = $(this).parent().css("background-image"),
    imageSource = zoomsign.split("/"),
    imageSource = imageSource[imageSource.length-1],
    imageSource = imageSource.substr(0, imageSource.length-2); 
    //console.log(imageSource);
    floatinMother.animate({top: "0%"}, 200);
    floating.css('background-image',  "url('img/" + imageSource + "')");
});
```

How can I solve it? Would you please give me a suggestion please?

Regards,
Omar.

Comment: show us the relevant html.

Comment: What is not working? Error message? Is imageSource what you expect?

Comment: How can it work in any browser? You load images with extension `.jp`.

Comment: 404 error image not find. `http://www.aqurds.com/img/port-image1.jp` should be `http://www.aqurds.com/img/port-image1.jpg` i guess issue comes from: `imageSource.length-2` in substring()

Comment: What is `imageSource` prior to the `substr()` line?

Comment: The only reason i can think of that inside `$('.zoomsign').on("click", function () { });` the different manipulations of `imageSource = zoomsign.split("/")` by using a `,` instead of `;` are different evaluated. But since OP does not care to set up a fiddle / codepen with the **[minimal code to reproduce the problem](http://sscce.org)**  why bother.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `imageSource = imageSource.substr(0, imageSource.length-2);`. This takes the `port-image1.jpg` portion of your image source and returns everything but the last character in the source string.

Comment: this doesn't address why OP's code works on other browsers. Unfortunately, without him giving us more info, its hard to guess what is happening.

Comment: still curious; I imagine he had that line in there at some point for a reason. Though it certainly seems unnessecary, and incorrect, and certainly seems to be the cause of the problem.

Comment: But, it's working in other browsers like firefox and IE. So, why chrome is not working?

Comment: Removing this line, may be the solution here. But, what is the alternate way to do the same thing here? As the imageSource is the string -- port-image1.jpg") and i want to cut off the last two characters -- ") by doing this code imageSource = imageSource.substr(0, imageSource.length-2); in firefox it is returning port-image1.jpg by cutting off the last two characters but chrome is returning port-image1.jp by cutting off the last 3 characters. Why is it happening? Doesn't chrome work the same way like other browsers for substr method? I think the question is now better cleat for everyone.

Answer (score -1):

Your `imagesource` is chopping off your last character.

It is returning `http://www.aqurds.com/img/port-image1.jp` and not `http://www.aqurds.com/img/port-image1.jpg` in Chrome.

Just comment out the `imageSource = imageSource.substr(0, imageSource.length-2);` line

Comment: Yes, that is true, already mentioned in comments but it is not a solution to the problem.

Comment: My question is why chrome is cutting off the last character and returning port-image1.jp Where firefox and other browser is returning port-image1.jpg ?

Comment: zgood, If i comment out this line how will i get the image source as string? Commenting out isn't the solution here, i think. Does "substr" method work differently in different browsers? Only firefox is cutting off the last character "g" and returning the string.

Comment: @user3166931 On this line: `imageSource = imageSource[imageSource.length-1]` imageSource has become a string from an array. The real question would be why Chrome isn't `split("/")`ing properly

Comment: "The real question would be why Chrome isn't split("/")ing properly" I agree and i want to know why it is happening?

Answer (score -2):

From Chrome console:

```
GET http://aqurds.com/img/port-image2.jp 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: Come on dude, i answered 1 minute later!
And for me it's an answer: he asked "How can i solve it? Would you please give me a **suggestion** please?"
The suggestion is "your image name is chopping"

Comment: Hmmm. You answered *a few* minutes later (it shows you the time), and this is definitely not an answer. It's a cut-paste of the console from OP's link. This is a restatement of the original problem more than an answer. Even "your image name is chopping" is not a suggestion. Its an observation. One you didn't even include. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer. I am not alone in this conclusion either. You recieved 3 downvotes immediately after posting (and 1 inexplicable upvote).

Comment: ok, ok. No problem. I'm here to learn and give an help when possible, nothing more.
Bye.

Comment: sorry to come off as so critical, Please don't let my negativity turn you away from participating. Thanks for attempting to contribute - that puts you above the vast majority of S.O. users in my book. Even if you're doing it wrong ;-)

Comment: As i said it's ok for me.